# How can I check if ALL the triggers are ON on Database?

Tags: sql, triggers

I want to check if all the triggers are on or not on the SQL Db I am working on.
How can I achieve that?
Thanks,

Comment: Please add which SQL DBMS product you are using.  And use more useful tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can do this:

Select * From sys.triggers

Comment: Thanks!

There is an is_disabled column in the result set.

Comment: Gosh, it's nice to hear/see someone actually say thanks. Thanks for saying "thanks" :)